# Python efficient assigning of even and odd bits to a bitstring/bit_array

Tags: python, performance, data-processing, bitarray, bitstring

I receive serialized DDR data from a setup with 8 chips. Due to the way the readout is implemented in hardware, the data that is received by the computer has the following structure:

bits 0 and 1 of Chip A, bits 0 and 1 of Chip B, ... bits 2 and 3 of Chip A, bits 2 and 3 of Chip B, ...

In order to make sense of the individual reply of each chip, the data needs to be split:

```
import bitstring

data = bitstring.BitArray(1024)  # contains serialized DDR data of 8 chips (here just 0 values for demo purposes)

even_bits_of_chip_A = data[0::16]  # starting at position 0, every 16th bit is an even bit of chip A
odd_bits_of_chip_A = data[1::16]  # starting at position 1, every 16th bit is an odd bit of chip A

data_of_chip_A = bitstring.BitArray(len(even_bits_of_chip_A) + len(odd_bits_of_chip_A))
data_of_chip_A[0::2] = even_bits_of_chip_A
data_of_chip_A[1::2] = odd_bits_of_chip_A
```

This code works fine and does what I want it to do. However, it is not that fast (considering I have to do this for all 8 chips, and generally with a lot more than 1024 bits). Is there a way to speed it up?

Of course the code can be rewritten like this:

```
import bitstring

data = bitstring.BitArray(1024)

data_of_chip_A = bitstring.BitArray(int(len(data) / 8))
data_of_chip_A[0::2] = data[0::16]
data_of_chip_A[1::2] = data[1::16]
```

This avoids the creation of the even_bits, odd_bits variables and increases performance. But the final step of assigning values to every second bit of `data_of_chip_A` still takes quite some time.
Is there a way to for example join two bit_arrays in "alternating" fashion?

Comment: What is `bitstring` and why are you using that?

Comment: Have you tried [bitarray](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/)?

Comment: How long is your real `data` and how much time do the different steps take?

Comment: You are bound by the speed of the chips, which might be an order of magnitude slower than the hardware you are running the Python on. If so, tweaking the Python code might make little difference.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I use bitstring because it was the first package that I came across when looking into bit-manipulation in python. Do you think bitarray would be faster in bit-wise assignment/does it have a way to "mix" two arrays in an alternating "bit-wise" fashion?

my real data is expected to be anywhere from 4'147'200 bits up to many multiples of that value.

The chips are read out with 100 MHz DDR (=200 Mbit/s * 8 chips = 1.6 Gbit/s), which makes the data processing the bottleneck. I don't need real-time processing, but fast would be good!

Comment: So if you *chose* that, then what is the actual input you start with? Also still unclear what bitstring is. I don't know their speeds, but bitarray is popular and implemented in C, *could* be faster. You're using basic operations, surely it can do those, too.

Comment: Also, I assume `bitstring.BitArray` is not your end goal then? What is?

Comment: My actual input is a `bytearray` (the payloads of multiple UDP packages). `bitstring.Bitarray` is a means to an end. The goal is to convert the content of each chip into an array of uint16 values. Each of the chips sends a series of uint16 values, but unfortunately these numbers get chopped up by the readout hardware as described above. Furthermore, after every x uint16 values, the readout hardware also inserts a "random" invalid bit that needs to be discarded before the conversion to uint16 can take place.

Comment: I suggest you show the whole code from `bytearray` to array of uint16 values. Then we can try alternatives to `bitstring.Bitarray`.

Comment: I see you're happy with `bitarray` now. I still think it might be possible to be faster by working with just Python's built-in types, and I enjoy doing such optimizations, but would need to know that bigger picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments, I switched to `bitarray`. It works fairly similar to `bitstring` and is way faster. Together with some simple `multiprocessing` the script runs 24x faster now. Thanks for the suggestions!

```
from bitarray import bitarray

data = bitarray(1024)  # empty/random array with 1024 bits
even_bits_of_chip_A = data[0::16]  # starting at position 0, every 16th bit is an even bit of chip A
odd_bits_of_chip_A = data[1::16]  # starting at position 1, every 16th bit is an odd bit of chip A

data_of_chip_A = bitarray(len(even_bits_of_chip_A) + len(odd_bits_of_chip_A))
data_of_chip_A[0::2] = even_bits_of_chip_A
data_of_chip_A[1::2] = odd_bits_of_chip_A
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that the stepping assignments are going to be quite slow as the `BitArray` is having to be manipulated a lot to remain as a dense object representing the data. It could be faster to instead go via a string as an intermediary:

```
import bitstring

data = bitstring.BitArray(1024)
data_bin = data.bin  # Convert to ordinary str of '0' and '1's
# Create a list to contain single '0' or '1' characters
data_of_chip_A_bin = [''] * (len(data) // 8)
data_of_chip_A_bin[0::2] = data_bin[0::16]
data_of_chip_A_bin[1::2] = data_bin[1::16]
# Convert back to dense binary object
data_of_chip_A = bitstring.BitArray(bin=''.join(data_of_chip_A_bin))
```

...or that might be slower. Hard to tell without more work. In general the bitarray module mentioned in the comments is going to be faster doing the bit manipulation work in the original answer as it's a compiled C module as opposed to working in pure Python.

Comment: You're using a list. I rather suspect that's slower. Could you benchmark them?

Comment: Quick test for 1 Gigabit of data time reduced from 9s to 6s, so not a great improvement. I also tried an alternative approach to interleave the data by padding them with zeros and interleaving with a bit-wise OR. It was about the same speed.

Comment: How about if you use `bytearray` / `bytes` (or just `bytearray`) instead of `list` / `string`? That should be faster.

Comment: Yes I tried using a plain `bytearray` too, which is helpfully mutable, but that was 10x slower for me. I may try it in bitarray later if I get a chance...

Comment: Surprising. From start `str` to final `str` (I don't know whether `BitArray` supports conversion to/from `bytes` or `bytearray`), it's ~3x faster for me. Can you share how you used it? [Mine](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyWxJDE@KTNPwVZB3UBdQUvB0EBLy4KLC0kcxtRLzUvOT0nV0IRI5qfFJ2dkFsQ7QpUlVZakJhYVJVZq5KTmacA0aSro6ytYYNMSbWBlZRSLZD5IwNAsFptSQ3SlhtiUwhSg6NVLSYW4@v9/AA).

Comment: (Also, note the question's comments, they actually start with a `bytearray`, and I suspect we'd better just stick with that and not go through `BitArray` and `str`. Waiting for them to show what they do with their input `bytearray`...)

Comment: Yep, @KellyBundy your method is faster. On my machine that takes 4s for 1 Gigabit of data (I also added in a conversion back to a packed binary object).